Dep extraction rules using NLPPort
When I'm trying to extract to deps from chunk and entities (even from depchunks) from sentence extract "A Lua e o Sol estão muito distantes." I got some entries like this:
(...)
A: Triple [subject=o Sol, predicate=ser, object=A Lua]
[A: o <START:thing> Sol <END> ser A <START:thing> Lua <END>]
A: Triple [subject=A Lua, predicate=ser, object=o Sol]
[A: A <START:thing> Lua <END> ser o <START:thing> Sol <END>]

B: Triple [subject=A Lua e o Sol, predicate=estar, object=muito distantes]
[B: A <START:thing> Lua <END> e o <START:thing> Sol <END> estar muito distantes]



--> [Attention!]  E: Triple [subject=o Sol, predicate=ser, object=A Lua]
[E: o <START:thing> Sol <END> ser A <START:thing> Lua <END>]
E: Triple [subject=estão, predicate=ser, object=muito distantes]
[E: estão ser muito distantes]
--> [Attention!] E: Triple [subject=A Lua, predicate=ser, object=o Sol]
[E: A <START:thing> Lua <END> ser o <START:thing> Sol <END>]

F: Triple [subject=A Lua e o Sol, predicate=estar, object=muito distantes]
[F: A <START:thing> Lua <END> e o <START:thing> Sol <END> estar muito distantes]
(...)

How can I adjust the pipeline from NLPPORT to skip (or improve) this rule that tell us that Lua is a subject and "o Sol" an object when we have connections between two entities ("e", cc)  + ("Lua", conj) ?
Is this right ?
If I use deps to create a KG to KBQA from a question "O sol é a lua ?" I will have entries like this:
E: Triple [subject=é, predicate=ser, object=a lua]
[E: é ser a lua]
F: Triple [subject=O sol, predicate=ser, object=a lua]
[F: O sol ser a lua]

So, I think will be a problem. I think that correct would be "O Sol e a Lua" are two subjects connected  by ('e' cc) being one only entity (or two?) suffering the action of same verb.
